# MUI Select - change icon background color when on hover

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently working to customize MUI `Select` method, However, I found it is difficult to hover the "NarrowDownIcon":

[image]

I want to change the `backgroundColor` of this icon to "blue" when hover it, this is my code:

```
icon: {
  color:        theme.palette.primary.dark,
  height:       32,
  width:        32,
  top:          `calc(50% - ${theme.spacing(2.2)}px)`,
  borderRadius: "50%",
  cursor:       "pointer",

  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.lighter,
  },
},
```

then i applied this css to select icon class:

```
  <Select
      value={selectedValue}
      onChange={onChange}
      onFocus={onFocus}
      onBlur={onBlur}
      className={classes.textInput}
      inputProps={{
        id,
        name: id,
      }}
      classes={{
        icon: classes.icon,
      }}
```

but it doesn't work , can anyone help me with this, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the icon color when you hover anywhere inside Select:

```
root: {
  "&:hover .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
    color: "red"
  }
},
```

```
<Select className={classes.root}>
```

To change the icon color when you only hover on the icon itself (not the input field). Note that your code doesn't work because the icon has `pointerEvents` set to `none`:

```
icon: {
  pointerEvents: "auto",
  "&:hover": {
    color: "red"
  }
}
```

```
<Select classes={{ icon: classes.icon }}>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: @vincent you may want to ask another question.

Comment: yes, I re-eidted my question, could you please help me again ? Thank you

Comment: @vincent create a new post for your separate question please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69708592/mui-select-how-can-i-add-a-fixed-layer-inside-the-popper-paper
@NearHuscarl , could you please help me with this ? thank you